# Como poder utilizar efectivamente la sentencia regroup de django cuando se tiene mas de de 2 niveles

Tags: django, django-models

Hola Queridos amigos, por mas que lo intento estoy tratando de mostrar los Planes, sus Objetivos Generales, específicos y sus respectivas tareas, como pueden observar tienen un modo jerárquico,  un plan puede tener muchos objetivos generales, así como también objetivos específicos y tareas

```
PLan 1: ABXC
 - Objetivo General 1
     Sub-Objetivo : 1
      Tarea 1
      Tarea 2
     Sub-Objetivo : 2
      Tarea 1
PLan 2: xxxx
 - Objetivo General 1
     Sub-Objetivo : 1
      Tarea 1
```

He intentado hacerlo del mil formas por ejemplo:

```
 {% regroup planlist by actionplan as plan_list %}
            {% for plan in plan_list %} <br>
                {{plan.grouper.description }}<br>
                {% regroup planlist by planobjective as obj_list %}
                {% for obj in obj_list %}
                    OBJETIVO: {{ obj.grouper }} <br>
                    {% regroup planlist by plansubobjective as subobj_list %}
                    {%for subobj in subobj_list %}
                        SUBOBJETIVO: {{ subobj.grouper}} <br>
                    {%endfor%}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Sin embargo no consigo hacer que funcione o se vea de la manera que quiero que aparazcan en la pagina.:
estes el queryset que estoy utilizando:

```
planlist = PlanSubObjectiveTask.objects.select_related ( 'actionplan' ).filter (
        actionplan_id__in=planvalues ).order_by('created_at')
```

Si me podéis dar una mano os agradezco.

```
Modelos: 
class ActionPlan(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField ( max_length=250, null=False, default='' )

class PlanObjective(models.Model):
    actionplan = models.ForeignKey ( ActionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    description = models.TextField ( max_length=1750, null=False, default='')
    
class PlanSubObjective ( models.Model ) :
    actionplan = models.ForeignKey ( ActionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    planobjective = models.ForeignKey ( PlanObjective, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    description = models.TextField ( max_length=1750, null=False, default='' )
    
class PlanSubObjectiveTask ( models.Model ) :
    actionplan = models.ForeignKey ( ActionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    planobjective  = models.ForeignKey ( PlanObjective, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    plansubobjective = models.ForeignKey ( PlanSubObjective, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    description = models.TextField ( max_length=1750, null=False, default='' )
```

Comment: Adjunta tus modelos y explica mas detalladamente el resultado que quieres obtener, de esta manera nos facilitaras el ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias @JulioCesar, perdón olvide adjuntar los modelos, como podéis ver los modelos están todos enlazados,  simplemente quiero mostrar las  en una lista jearquica quien pertenece a quien.